# PSQL get duplicate row

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have table like this-

```
id        object_id       product_id          
1         1                1                  
2         1                1                  
4         2                2                  
6         3                2                  
7         3                2                  
8         1                2                  
9         1                1
```

I want to delete all rows except these-

```
1         1                 1      
4         2                 2
6         3                 2         
9         1                 2
```

Basically there are duplicates and I want to remove them but keep one copy intact.

what would be the most efficient way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a one-off then you can simply identify the records you want to keep like so:

```
SELECT MIN(id) AS id
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY object_id, product_id;
```

You want to check that this works before you do the next thing and actually throw records out. To actually delete those duplicate records you do:

```
DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT MIN(id) AS id
  FROM yourtable
  GROUP BY object_id, product_id
);
```

The `MIN(id)` obviously always returns the record with the lowest id for a set of (`object_id`, `product_id`). Change as desired.