# Remove duplicates (same lines)

Tags: sql

I have a table with the two columns `a` and `b`.

I can have data like :

```
a  | b  
1  | 1  
1  | 3 
1  | 3   
2  | 2   
2  | 3   
2  | 2
2  | 2
```

In my example, `a=2,b=2` and `a=1,b=3` are duplicate.

How can I remove all this duplicate from my table?

Comment: You still want to keep one a=2,b=2 row?

Comment: Remove from table or display (select) without duplicates?

Comment: Remove from table, and i neek to keep one line each time

Comment: Create a copy table, do INSERT INTO tmp SELECT DISTINCT a,b FROM original_table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18932/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554060/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1286843/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3311903/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23690867/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6583916/330315 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/31315856/330315

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only for display use `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM your_table
```

Delete from old table (intrusive way), but I suppose you don't have any foreign keys on it. **(MySql)**

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table;

DROP TABLE old_table;

RENAME TABLE new_table TO old_table;
```

More general way (no need to drop original table):

```
CREATE TABLE old_table_clone(...);

INSERT INTO old_table_clone(...)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM old_table;

TRUNCATE TABLE old_table;

INSERT INTO old_table(...)
SELECT * FROM old_table_clone;

DROP TABLE old_table_clone;
```

The same may be achieved using temp table, dependent on which RDBMS you use like **TSQL/SQL Server**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #temp FROM old_table;

TRUNCATE TABLE old_table;

INSERT INTO old_table(...)
SELECT * FROM #temp;
```

Comment: CREATE ... AS SELECT is product specific functionality, please specify which one!

Comment: You can also create the table, add a unique index, and insert ignore.

Comment: @jarlh: `create table .. as select ..` is defined in the SQL standard. `select .. into` is non-standard functionality

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for correcting. (I tend to forget non-core functionality... Feature T172, “AS subquery clause in table definition”.)

Answer (score 0):

Check:
[Delete duplicate records using rownum in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067033/delete-duplicate-records-using-rownum-in-sql)

If you don't have rowid in your database, add unique ID